# Angular build error :"Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl'"

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

here is the error that I get when I try to compile (ng build --prod):

```
Error at /angular/src/app/.../xxx.component.html(xx,xxx): Argument of type 'AbstractControl' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl'.
  Property 'registerOnChange' is missing in type 'AbstractControl'.
```

the problematic codes (assumptions) :

```
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            oneField: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,customValidator()])
        });
```

and :

```
    ngChangeOnefield(event: FormControl){
        // some code...
    }
```

In my html component, I have something like :

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    <!-- more code -->
    <htmltag (onSelect)="ngChangeOneField(oneField)"/>
    <!-- more code -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this issue by changing that code :

```
    ngChangeOnefield(event: FormControl){
        // some code...
    }
```

to

```
    ngChangeOnefield(event: AbstractControl){
        // some code...
    }
```

So for the **event** triggering, the good type of the event is **AbstractControl** and not FormControl

Comment: hell yes!!!! this solved my problem, thank you so much for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

Just put type of return `:any` changing that code:

```
ngChangeOnefield(event: FormControl){
  // some code...
}
```

To:

```
ngChangeOnefield(event: FormControl) :any {
  // some code...
}
```